# How to change the temporary used directory by sqoop-import?

Tags: java, hive, hdfs, sqoop, tmp

I've been using a `sqoop-import` command like this:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@${machine}:${port}/${schema} --username ${user} --password ${pw} --table "${table}" --columns "${cols}" --where "${machine}" --m 1 --fields-terminated-by ';' --target-dir ${dir} --hive-table "${hive_table}"
```

It has worked properly until now, when I receive this message:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/data/tmp
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Insufficient space for shared memory file:
   64215
Try using the -Djava.io.tmpdir= option to select an alternate temp location.
```

Indeed my /tmp is full:

`/dev/mapper/system-lv_tmp   5136000  4875796 0 100% /tmp`

I cannot delete files that are not mine in /tmp so i can't free up enough space there.

I've tried changing the `_JAVA_OPTIONS` to another directory but still get the same error.

Is there any way to make the command use a different directory for temporal files?

Comment: Is `/data/tmp` the same as `/tmp`? If you still get the same error (`Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/data/tmp`) even if you've supplied a different directory in `_JAVA_OPTIONS` it seems the `_JAVA_OPTIONS` you supply and the options `sqoop` uses aren't the same.

Comment: Indeed /data/tmp and /tmp are different directories... The error message only appears when /tmp is full. /data/tmp has space available... The thing is, can i tell sqoop to use another directory that is not /tmp in any way?

Comment: I thought I found a way by looking in the source code, but apparently it didn't work so I removed the answer.

Comment: One idea if everything else fails is to just download the source, change all lines containing `/tmp` to `/data/tmp` and then compile your own version of `sqoop`.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the Java property `java.io.tmpdir` and has nothing to do with Sqoop.

From the [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html):

> The default temporary-file directory is specified by the system
>   property `java.io.tmpdir`.

Sqoop is not setting the value for `tmpdir`. But you can override this value when running your `sqoop import` command.

```
sqoop import -Djava.io.tmpdir=/path/to/new/tmp ...
```

Comment: I already changed the _JAVA_OPTIONS var to another directory as it was shown by the command when launched, but still it created files on /tmp. /data/tmp is not the same as /tmp

Comment: Sure, this is launched from bash, so in that environment i set _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=/path/to/new/tmp"

Comment: The sqoop -import would show when launch: Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/path/to/new/tmp. I believe this to be the same that you answered.

Comment: But do you get the same error even after it says that it has picked up a new value for `java.io.tmpdir`?

Comment: What is the OS and java version?

Comment: Yes, i get the same error no matter what is the value of `java.io.tmpdir`

Comment: OS is Linux and Java version is 1.8.0_60

Comment: Looks like the JVM is ignoring the value set by the program or the environment. Let us try this `export TMPDIR=/path/to/new/tmp`. Also, did you try running as mentioned in the answer, did it behave the same ?

Comment: Neither of them work. The behaviour is the same, keeps going to /tmp

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is the code generated for Sqoop, there are several code generation control arguments like:

[image]

For example, you could try this:

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@${machine}:${port}/${schema} \
--username ${user} \
--password ${pw} \
--table "${table}" \
--columns "${cols}" \
--where "${machine}" \
--m 1 \
--fields-terminated-by ';' \
--target-dir ${dir} \
--hive-table "${hive_table}" \
--outdir /home/user/outdir_directory \
--bindir /home/user/bindir_directory
```

and the **java** files generated for `Sqoop` are going to go to `{outdir_directory and bindir_directory}` so you can delete these whenever you want.

Comment: have you created /home/user/outdir_directory and --bindir /home/user/bindir_directory directories? because if them don't exists sqoop doesn't create them for you.

Comment: and you have to be sure that sqoop has the right permissions to write in there